# Expression of type 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable`1[Model]' cannot be used for return type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable`1[Model]

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have the following code:

```
IQueryable<Container> containers = this.Repository.Containers.AsNoTracking();
var expressions = new List<IQueryable<Container>>();
var sortingExpressions = new List<Func<IQueryable<Container>, IOrderedQueryable<Container>>>();

var containers2 = containers.Where(x => EF.Functions.Like(x.Description, $"%{message.SearchValue}%"));
if (containers2.Any())
{
    var containers2Sorting = new Func<IQueryable<Container>, IOrderedQueryable<Container>>(x => x
                                .OrderBy(y => y.Description)
                                .ThenByDescending(y => y.DateUpdated));

    expressions.Add(containers2);
    sortingExpressions.Add(containers2Sorting);
}

var containers3 = containers.Where(x => x.ContactEmails
                                    .Any(y => EF.Functions.Like(y.Email, $"%{message.SearchValue}%")
                                            || EF.Functions.Like(y.DisplayName, $"%{message.SearchValue}%")));
if (containers3.Any())
{
    var containers3Sorting = new Func<IQueryable<Container>, IOrderedQueryable<Container>>(x => x
                                .OrderBy(y => y.ContactEmails.OrderBy(z => z.Email).ThenBy(z => z.DisplayName))
                                .ThenByDescending(y => y.DateUpdated));

    expressions.Add(containers3);
    sortingExpressions.Add(containers3Sorting);
}

if (expressions.Any())
{
    var mergedContainers = expressions.Aggregate((acc, i) => acc.Union(i));

    if (sortingExpressions.Any())
    {
        var mergedSorting = sortingExpressions
                                    .Aggregate((acc, next) => q => next(acc(q)));

        containers = mergedSorting(mergedContainers);
    }
    else
    {
        containers = mergedContainers.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateUpdated);
    }
}
else
{
    containers = Enumerable.Empty<Container>().AsQueryable();
}

var total = containers.Count();
```

And the latest row of code throw error:

```
"Expression of type 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable`1[AC.DBModels.Entities.ContactEmail]' cannot be used for return type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable`1[AC.DBModels.Entities.ContactEmail]
```

If I remove:

```
.OrderBy(y => y.ContactEmails.OrderBy(z => z.Email).ThenBy(z => z.DisplayName))
```

Then everything is fine.

I also tried to replace this row with:

```
.OrderBy(y =>
{
    y.ContactEmails = y.ContactEmails.OrderBy(z => z.Email).ThenBy(z => z.DisplayName);
    return y.Id;
})
```

And I have error: `Can't implicitly convert IOrderedEnumerable to List`

When I add `.ToList()`:

```
.OrderBy(y =>
{
    y.ContactEmails = y.ContactEmails.OrderBy(z => z.Email).ThenBy(z => z.DisplayName).ToList();
    return y.Id;
})
```

I have errors: `lambda expression with a statement body can't converted be converted to expression tree` and `expression tree may not contain assignment operator`

How can I resolve this issue?

Example:
`dbo.Containers`

```
| Id  | Description |
|-----|-------------|
|  1  |    abc      |
|  2  |    test3    |
|  3  |    test2    |
|  4  |    test1    |
|  5  |    cba      |
|  6  |    123      |
```

`dbo.ContactEmails`

```
| Id | ContainerId | DisplayName   | Email         |
|----|-------------|---------------|---------------|
|  1 |           1 | test2@abc.com | test2@abc.com |
|  2 |           2 | abc@abc.com   | abc@abc.com   |
|  3 |           3 | abc@abc.com   | abc@abc.com   |
|  4 |           4 | abc@abc.com   | abc@abc.com   |
|  5 |           5 | test1@abc.com | test1@abc.com |
|  6 |           6 | 123@abc.com   | 123@abc.com   |
```

Search value = "test" and in result I got:
`dbo.Containers`

```
| Id | Description |
|----|-------------|
| 4  | test1       |
| 3  | test2       |
| 2  | test3       |
| 5  | cba "because dbo.ContactEmails 5 - 5 - test1@abc.com - test1@abc.com" |
| 1  | abc "because dbo.ContactEmails 1 - 1 - test2@abc.com - test2@abc.com" |
```

Comment: EF Core convert the expression to SQL. Try to convert this in SQL. You can't, EF neither.

Comment: Can you explain the expect result? The best is to show the expected SQL.

Comment: I want to find containers with using full text search by multiple parameters/search values   with importance: first by Desccription, second by ContactEmails. Then merge them and then sort them. I can't sort them in initial query because after merging sorting is reset

Comment: How do you plan to sort by collection of elements? There is no SQL equivalent.

Comment: Do you mean I can't sort by collection? Where in code I can sort Emails?

Comment: Sure you can't sort by collection, it has no sense. You can sort `ContactEmails` only in projection.

Comment: The containers found because the description, are they sorted by `ContactEmails`?

Comment: If containers found just by description then sort by ContactEmails disabled if containers found by both fields then we need to sort by Description first then by ContactEmails

Comment: My main goal - concatenate containers (with uniqueness) without resetting order

Comment: Can you add data example?

Comment: Can a container have multiple contact emails? Otherwise, you can simplify the model.

Comment: Yes, container can have multiple contact emails

Answer (score 0):

The method `OrderBy` expect a projection that describe how get the value to compare, like you do with `Description` :

```
.OrderBy(y => y.Description)
```

But with :

```cs
.OrderBy(y => 
    y.ContactEmails.OrderBy(z => z.Email).ThenBy(z => z.DisplayName)
)
```

This don't work, because the projection return a `IOrderedEnumerable`, that isn't comparable. A valid projection can be :

```cs
.OrderBy(y => 
    y.ContactEmails.OrderBy(z => z.Email).First().Email
)
.ThenBy(y => 
    y.ContactEmails.OrderBy(z => z.DisplayName).First().DisplayName
)
```

---

For your use case, you can do a heavy Linq query that will be translated to heavy sql query... but I don't recommend, because it isn't optimized.

If you don't have pagination, you can do simple queries to get result and join/sort in C#.

```cs
var containersWithDescriptionLike = context.Containers.AsNoTracking()
    .Where(c => c.Description.Contains(searchValue))
    .AsEnumerable() // Get the result from the server
    .OrderBy(c => c.Description) // Sort in client
    .ToList();

var containersWithContactLike = context.Containers.AsNoTracking()
    .Where(c =>
        !containersWithDescriptionLike.Contains(c) &&
        c.ContactEmails.Any(e => e.Email.Contains(searchValue) || e.DisplayName.Contains(searchValue))
    )
    .AsEnumerable() // Get the result from the server
    // Sort in client
    .OrderBy(c => c.ContactEmails.Where(e => e.Email.Contains(searchValue)).Min(e => e.Email))
    .ThenByDescending(c => c.ContactEmails.Where(e => e.DisplayName.Contains(searchValue)).Min(e => e.DisplayName))
    .ToList();

// Join two dataset
var containers = containersWithDescriptionLike.Concat(containersWithContactLike).ToList();
```

Comment: I need unique containers, `.Concat` will get all as far as I know and it's why I used `.Union` that reset my sorting. And not sure how `.Min()` works here, can you explain please?

Comment: `.Min(e => e.DisplayName)` is equivalent to `.OderBy(e => e.DisplayName).First()`. It's to take the best value from the collection, as the value to compare.

Comment: I update the answer to retrieve unique containers.